# Which UTM zone 32N with prefix should I use in Rhineland-Palatinate (Germany)?

Tags: coordinate-system, utm, germany

I would like to store and use GIS-Data in Rhineland-Palatinate (Germany). The coordinate System should be UTM 32N **with 32 as prefix** (false easting = 32,500,000; not 500,000).

I looked at **EPSG 4647** [ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (zE-N)].
But I'm confused because EPSG says:

> Scope:  Used in Schleswig-Holstein.
>
> Information Source: Landesvermessungsamt Schleswig-Holstein.

Which UTM 32N coordinate system (EPSG-code) should use in Rhineland-Palatinate?

EDIT:

I will convert a large database from Gauss-Krueger to UTM. The database (and the new coordinate system) will be used for many years. We will exchange data with other (UTM with and without prefix, Gauss-Kueger).

Since 4647 to refers to Schleswig-Holstein I am not sure whether 4647 is good for us. But there are no  other EPSG codes with zone prefix.

Comment: We use 4647 in Lower Saxony, too. As far as i know, 4647, 25832 and the other EPSG-UTM32-Codes only differ in representation, that is 4647 stores with preceeding zone number, whereas 25832 doesnt. So 25832 coordinate xxxxxx is 32xxxxxx in 4647.

Comment: See also http://www.lgn.niedersachsen.de/download/71484/Massgeschneiderte_EPSG-Codes_fuer_GIS-Anwendungen.pdf. This is not restricted to Schleswig-Holstein

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use 4647 in Lower Saxony, too. As far as i know, 4647 and 25832 only differ in representation, that is 4647 stores with preceeding zone number, whereas 25832 doesnt. So 25832 coordinate xxxxxx is 32xxxxxx in 4647.

(Please note that some other EPSG codes for UTM32N, for example 5652, swich the N and E coordinates (thanks @Jens))

See http://www.epsg-registry.org/ for more details.

Comment: I suggest that you delete the part _and the other EPSG-UTM32-Codes_. Because _other EPSG-UTM32-Codes_ differ in the order of xy axis. Then I will accept your answer.